# XPath contains() Search for Exact Match

Tags: php, regex, xpath

Is it possible to search a DOMDocument object with fn:contains and return true on only an exact match for a word?

I have a text replacement snippet that I did not write myself that does internal link replacements for keywords.  But as written it also replaces partial words instead of only the full word.

Here is the snippet:

```
$autolinks = $this->config->get('autolinks');
if (isset($autolinks) && (strpos($this->data['description'], 'iframe') == false) 
        && (strpos($this->data['description'], 'object') == false)):
    $xdescription = mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($this->data['description'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"); 
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;             
    $dom->loadHTML('<div>'.$xdescription.'</div>');             
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    foreach ($autolinks as $autolink):
        $keyword    = $autolink['keyword'];
        $xlink  = mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($autolink['link'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
        $target     = $autolink['target'];
        $tooltip    = isset($autolink['tooltip']);                          
        $pTexts     = $xpath->query(
            sprintf('///text()[contains(., "%s")]', $keyword)
        );
        foreach ($pTexts as $pText):
            $this->parseText($pText, $keyword, $dom, $xlink, $target, $tooltip);
        endforeach;
    endforeach;
    $this->data['description'] = $dom->saveXML($dom->documentElement);
endif;
```

In example:

If my keyword is "massage" **massage**r is partially matched and converted to a link, when only the whole word massage should be converted, not massager.

Comment: Example xml would be useful.  What do you have as input that produces bad output and what is the input where you want the changes?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're asking for. I need to know how match whole words only within the `$xpath->query(sprintf('///text()[contains(., "%s")]', $keyword));` section above.  As I said, the input ie: `$keyword` variable would be "massage" and the output in error is that the word "massager" is being linked on only the word massage with the ending "r" remaining unlinked as plain text. The word "massager" should not be matched at all since it's not the exact keyword.

Comment: Would massage in the xml node <Tagname>This is a sentence containing the word massage.</Tagname> be a match? Or are all matches on the form <Tagname>massage</Tagname>

Comment: Yes the `$this->data['description']` is a block of text, the description of a product. So yes `<Tagname>This is a sentence containing the word massage.</Tagname>` would be a match, but currently so is `<Tagname>This is a sentence containing the word massager.</Tagname>` which is what I'd like to eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be incredibly simple, I just added a space onto the end of the `$keyword` variable so now it only returns true when the entire word is found.

```
foreach ($autolinks as $autolink):
    $keyword    = trim($autolink['keyword']) . ' ';
    $xlink      = mb_convert_encoding(html_entity_decode($autolink['link'], ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8"), 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $target     = $autolink['target'];
    $tooltip    = isset($autolink['tooltip']);                          
    $pTexts     = $xpath->query(
        sprintf('///text()[contains(., "%s")]', $keyword)
    );
    foreach ($pTexts as $pText):
        $this->parseText($pText, $keyword, $dom, $xlink, $target, $tooltip);
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 3):

You should use fn:matches instead of fn:contains.  This allows you to do matching with regular expressions.  Then you can include word boundaries with \b.

```
sprintf('///text()[matches(., "\b%s\b")]', $keyword)
```

Note that this does not affect whatever your function parseText is doing.  So while `<Tagname>This is a sentence containing the word massager.</Tagname>` will be unaffected, I make no guarantee what will happen to `<Tagname>The massager give the customer a massage.</Tagname>`.  To make sure that this is handled properly your parsetext function will need to be modified.  Possibly in a similar manner as above.

Note also that the modifications you might need to make to parsetext means that the above change becomes unecessary.

Comment: Apparently fn:matches is not available in XSLT 1.0 / XPATH 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 is not available for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Text manipulation in XSLT 1.0 is very limited, but if you can't move to 2.0 (why not?) then `translate()` often comes to the rescue. Use `translate()` to replace all common punctuation characters by spaces, use `concat()` to add a space fore and aft, and then test for `contains(' massage ')` (note the spaces).

Comment: XSLT 2.0 is not available in PHP that I can find. Do you have an example of how to use `translate()`?

Comment: If you're seriously into XSLT - like if you're writing more XSLT than PHP - then it's worth looking at solutions that invoke a Java XSLT processor, eg. over HTTP. Examples of translate() - yes, there are many examples in my book.

Answer (score 1):

When `matches()`, `ends-with()` are not supported, you can use `starts-with()` and `string-length()` to get around.

Example:

```
[starts-with(.,'$var') and string-length(.)=string-length('$var')]
```

This is equivalent to `matches()`.

Comment: This saved me from hours of a headache. Thanks